# Reason for corrupted /var/lib/logrotate/status

Tags: linux, unix, redhat

I'm using logrotate 3.7.1 to rotate my logs.Recently I found that the logrotate getting failed and the reason was /var/lib/logrotate/status file getting corrupted.I have cleared the log file and run the logrotate  and it worked correctly.

I want to know for what reason the file getting corrupted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*(You are not providing the most crucial piece of information, i.e. what exactly you mean by "failed" and "corrupted". Without that information I can only take a shot in the dark...)*

`logrotate` should be able to rotate *any* file, regardless of their contents - as far as I know all it does is rename and compress the file. A file with corrupt contents would be processed just the same as any other file.

With that in mind, I can only think that the cause of the `logrotate` failure is what caused the log file corruption in the first place. I'd start by having a closer look at your storage hardware - e.g. a disk failure could corrupt a log file and then cause an I/O error when it is read, thus stopping `logrotate` in its tracks.

Answer (score 1):

in general file corruption on Unix variants operating system can happen for several reasons.
Material defect on disk which often leave indication in syslog is one.
kill -9 on a process currently re-writing the file for files greater than OS native block size.
Violent and unexpected power loss which might lead in some hardware arrangement to abrupt shutdown.
No space on disk incident which is not very well tolerated by utility.
A second or more copy’s of utility running where  proper locking mechanism was not included or deemed  necessary for the file in question.
I will recommend using “/usr/sbin/logrotate -dv /etc/logrotate.conf” on boot to detect, fix and log such incident on 24/7 setups.

Answer (score 0):

You have to post the specific error message from `logrotate` when parsing the corrupted status file, as it indicates the line number in the file that corrupted it.

In my case, for example, it was invalid UTF-8 byte sequences in filename patterns being processed; the root cause wasn't in `logrotate` but in the programs that had created those logs.

Answer (score 0):

If somehow there are multiple concurrent running logrotate, the status file could easily get corrupted, this is true when there are multiple uses of logrotate and some are configured with cron job directly (instead of adding configure entry to /etc/logrotate.d) or logrotate gets run manually.